# Understanding sklearn GridSearchCV's best_score_ and best_estimator_

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, cross-validation

In the code below, I am trying to understand the connection between `best_estimator_` and `best_score_`. I think that I should be able to get (at least a very close approximation) to `best_score_` by scoring the results of `best_estimator_` like so:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

classifier = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(penalty='l1'),
                          {'C':10**(np.linspace(1,6,num=11))},
                          scoring='neg_log_loss')

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.best_estimator_.predict(X_train)
print(f'{log_loss(y_train,y_pred)}') 
print(f'{classifier.best_score_}')
```

However I get the following outputs (the numbers do not vary much on different runs):

```
7.841241697018637
-0.5470694752031108
```

I understand that `best_score_` will be calculated as an average of the cross-validation iterations, however this should surely be a close approximation (an unbiased estimator even?) of calculating the metric on the whole set. I don't understand why they are so very different so I assume that I've made an implementation error.

How can I calculate `classifier.best_score_` myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log_loss is mostly defined for `predict_proba()`.
I am assuming that GridSearchCV is internally calling predict_proba and then calculating the score.

Please change the `predict()` to `predict_proba()` and you will see similar results.

```
y_pred = classifier.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X)

print(log_loss(y_train,y_pred)) 
print(classifier.best_score_)
```

On iris dataset, I am getting the following output:

```
0.165794760809
-0.185370083771
```

which looks quite close.

Update:

Looks like this is the case: When you supply `'loss_loss'` as a string to GridSearchCV, [this is how](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L518) its initialized as a scorer to be passed on to [`_fit_and_score()` method of GridSearchCV()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L631):

```
log_loss_scorer = make_scorer(log_loss, greater_is_better=False,
                              needs_proba=True)
```

As you can see, the [`needs_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) is true, means that for scoring predict_proba() will be used.

Comment: Of course! Thanks! The scores are now `0.4930534590910885`
`-0.5471970784999165` which is much closer, still ~10% off though, I guess that is effected by sample size and number of folds though

Comment: @Dan Yes, I think so. To still exactly match the scores, you can instantiate a LogisticRegression object with classifier.best_params_, and then take the mean of results from cross_val_score(logReg, X_train, y_train, scoring='neg_log_loss'). Make sure to set the random_state though. cross_val_score and GridSearchCV will use same cv strategy if not explicitly set.